# Building an lambda zip file on the commandline in AWS codebuild fails with "the required library libhostfxr.so could not be found"

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, aws-lambda

I am running a command during a AWS CodeBuild in order to build a lambda zip file.

The command is as follows:

```
dotnet lambda package --framework netcoreapp2.1 -o ../../artifacts/Jobs.zip
```

Here is the error:

```
**A fatal error occurred, the required library libhostfxr.so could not be found.
If this is a self-contained application, that library should exist in [/root/.dotnet/tools/.store/amazon.lambda.tools/3.3.1/amazon.lambda.tools/3.3.1/tools/netcoreapp2.1/any/].
If this is a framework-dependent application, install the runtime in the default location [/usr/share/dotnet] or use the DOTNET_ROOT environment variable to specify the runtime location.
Makefile:28: recipe for target 'Jobs/artifacts/Jobs.zip' failed**

Because this is a container I have printed out the dotnet info:

.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):

 Version:   2.2.402
 Commit:    c7f2f96116
 Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  18.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.18.04-x64
 Base Path:   /root/.dotnet/sdk/2.2.402/

Host (useful for support):
 Version: 3.1.2
 Commit:  916b5cba26

.NET Core SDKs installed:

2.2.402 [/root/.dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:

Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.7 [/root/.dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.7 [/root/.dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.2 [/root/.dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.7 [/root/.dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.2 [/root/.dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

So the project in Visual Studio is targeting .NET Core 2.1

This issue just started about 10 days ago.  I was able to go back to an earlier commit, push it to GitHub which kicks of the code build in AWS.  This earlier commit, when pushed 2 weeks ago was successful and I did not see this libhostfxr.so error.  Basically anything I push now I get the above error. 
While researching I found that because I am using a Container, I can use the flag

```
--self-contained=true and /p:PreserveCompilationContext=true
```

so that I can bundle all dependencies but that has not worked either.

Not sure what else to try at this point.  Does anyone have any ideas?  The target framework for these lambdas is .NET core 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

After more research I found the solution here.  https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images/issues/321

I need to set the DOTNET_ROOT in my yml file.

Comment: A new blog [post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/automated-ci-cd-pipeline-for-net-core-lambda-functions-using-aws-extensions-for-dotnet-cli/) was published by AWS after this which may help.